# Script to run function based on div width

Tags: jquery, function, html, resize, width

I am in need of a script that will execute a function based on the width of a div.

I would like to be able to execute the function when the div is resized. So for instance if the div width is 300px then execute function 1, div width is 700px then execute function and so on.

Thank-you in advance!

Comment: You are in need of a book. Do something by yourself and then ask for help!

Comment: @Bakudan - this forum was created for people who have questions - if you get irritated that people don't search extensively for solutions before asking on SO then don't get on SO (simple solution).  We were all newbs at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking of the [jQuery UI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/)

```
  $( ".selector" ).resizable({
  resize: function(event, ui) {
  if($(this).width()>300)
  {
      //do some stuff
  }
  if($(this).width()>700)
  {
      //do some other stuff
  }
  }
  });
```

EDIT: OR Browser rezise

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 var width = $(".content_genre").width();
if(width>300)
 { 
     itemsPerPage = Number(30); initPaginator();
 }
});
```

Comment: I think so, basically when the browser window is shrunk down the div width changes, so i want to be able to fire a pagination function to change the number of divs on the screen.

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".content_genre").resizable({
        resize: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(this).width() > 300) {
                itemsPerPage = Number(30); initPaginator();
            }
            if ($(this).width() > 700) {
                itemsPerPage = Number(36); initPaginator();
            }
        }
    });
</script>

Comment: I think you're talking of Browser resize.. See EDIT

Comment: OK .. now would I be able to add multiple functions to browser resize in order to fire different functions for different resizes